# Reaching a value and dropping it in the next line in php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I went to WordPress with the WooCommerce categories. Now I want 3 columns. And in my code I'll say that whenever you get to 3, go next line. How do I implement it? These are the codes

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
    'orderby'      => 'name',
    'show_count'   => 0,
    'pad_counts'   => 0,
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'title_li'     => '',
    'hide_empty'   => 0
);
$all_categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
    if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
        echo "<div class='uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body align-cat'><a href='. get_term_link($cat->slug, product_cat) .'> {$cat->name} </a></div>";
        if($cat->name >= 3){
            return "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So *what* does not work *(and how exactly)* with the code you provided? What is its behaviour *and* what do you expect from it?

Comment: I want to be 3 pillars

Comment: To cite Smuuf: So what does not work (and how exactly) with the code you provided?

Comment: Probably something like `.uk-card{float:left; with:calc(33% - 20px);}  .product(orWhatEverYouArchiveIsNamed) .uk-card:nth-of-type(3n + 1){clear:both;}` or something like that

Answer (score 1):

Albeit things on a HTML page should be arranged using [CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets), in answer to your question *(if I understood it correctly)*:

You need to insert your `<br>` **after each 3rd `<div>`**. You do that using the `%` [modulo operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

```
$counter = 1;
foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
    if ($cat->category_parent == 0) {
        echo "<div class='uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body align-cat'><a href='. get_term_link($cat->slug, product_cat) .'> {$cat->name} </a></div>";
        if ($counter++ % 3 === 0) {
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

This will print `<br>` after 3rd, 6th, 9th, etc. category `<div>`.

Comment: I don't know where exactly does your `$cat->name` come from and I didn't want to make the gigantic assumption that it always would the following number from the previous category, so I introduced the `$counter` variable.

Comment: With modulo, don't you need a `$counter++;` or does that implement automatically?

Comment: Jesus, you're right! Not enough coffee this morning. Made the edit. Thanks.

Comment: The code you sent did not answer.
Please see this picture. I want to implement this in my form, but it's all in one row. I want to be this way

Comment: See this photo. I want something like that

http://s8.picofile.com/file/8323366334/Capture.PNG

Comment: I understand, and as I said, you should use CSS to arrange items on your page and not rely on `<br>` being inserted. *But* the code above **does insert** a line break after each third category `<div>` :) *(if the category's `category_parent == 0`)*.

Comment: This code does indeed input a `<br>` tag after each parent category outputtet - If you want to do it like in the picture, you should probably do it with CSS - but since you haven't shown us any real code and we don't know thee CSS of the classes, this answer is what you can expect... If your classes have `float`, then `<br>` tags probably won't work. if they have `inline-block` then this should work fine. You need to improve your question with specifics - this answer is probably the cleanest you will get as of now.

Comment: Thank you  Stender and  Smuuf , dear . fixed